# Android database closed exception

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm working on a project where I'm downloading and saving data from web to sqlite database. A few minutes ago I receive a strange exception to our server from a user which is saying that the sqlite database is already closed..and I just checked the whole file where the exception happened and I'm not calling `dbHelper.close();`. Here is the function where the app crashes and LogCat message :

```
public void insertCollectionCountries(JSONObject obj, Context context) {
    //Insert in collection_countries
    if(RPCCommunicator.isServiceRunning){
    Log.w("","JsonCollection - insertCollectionCountries");
    ContentValues valuesCountries = new ContentValues();

        try {
            collectionId = Integer.parseInt(obj.getString("collection_id"));
            dbHelper.deleteSQL("collection_countries", "collection_id=?", new String[] {Integer.toString(collectionId)});

           JSONArray arrayCountries = obj.getJSONArray("country_availability");
           for (int i=0; i<arrayCountries.length(); i++) {
                   valuesCountries.put("collection_id", collectionId);
                   String countryCode = arrayCountries.getString(i);
                   valuesCountries.put("country_code", countryCode);
                   dbHelper.executeQuery("collection_countries", valuesCountries);
           }
        } catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the error is on that line : `dbHelper.executeQuery("collection_countries", valuesCountries);`

here is the LogCat message  :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: database /data/data/com.stampii.stampii/databases/stampii_sys_tpl.sqlite (conn# 0) already closed
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.verifyDbIsOpen(SQLiteDatabase.java:2123)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful(SQLiteDatabase.java:734)
    at com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.SystemDatabaseHelper.execQuery(SystemDatabaseHelper.java:298)
    at com.stampii.stampii.comm.rpc.SystemDatabaseHelper.executeQuery(SystemDatabaseHelper.java:291)
    at com.stampii.stampii.jsonAPI.JsonCollection.insertCollectionCounries(JsonCollection.java:548)
    at com.stampii.stampii.jsonAPI.JsonCollection.executeInsert(JsonCollection.java:181)
    at com.stampii.stampii.collections.MyService.downloadCollections(MyService.java:122)
    at com.stampii.stampii.collections.MyService$2.run(MyService.java:74)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1020)
```

and function in my `dbHelperClass` which I'm using to insert data :

```
 public boolean executeQuery(String tableName,ContentValues values){
    return execQuery(tableName,values);
}

private  boolean execQuery(String tableName,ContentValues values){
    sqliteDb = instance.getWritableDatabase();
    sqliteDb.beginTransaction();
    sqliteDb.insert(tableName, null, values);
    sqliteDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
    sqliteDb.endTransaction();
    return true;
}
```

Any ideas which can close my sqlite database or what can cause that exception, because I've tested this code on a few emulators with different Android versions, different devices (HTC EVO 3D, Samsung Galaxy Nexus,HTC Desire, LG OPTIMUS PAD, Samsung Galaxy S2, Samsung Galaxy Note) and it's working fine.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look where you *do* close the db. Maybe in onClose().. also, see if you open it again in onResume() or similar..

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I can think of is to call the open() at the start of execQuery() and call close() just before returning the value.

Let me know if it helps you.

Answer (score -2):

If the user is using the latest version of Chrome, it is possible that the database was malformed and Chrome deleted it for you, and it is also possible that the exception is because the database was closed during normal page unload and transactions against a closed database no longer fail silently.